# How to concatenate columns row wise in excel file?

Tags: excel

I am trying to concatenate content of two different columns row wise but I am not getting a way by which I can do this with a single formula/condition.

```
  name       Surname
    A          B
    C          D
    E          F
    .............
```

And I want to display:

```
  A B
  C D
  E F
 .....
```

I know the formula to concatenate like =CONCATENATE(A1," ",B1).
But I know that I can do this for individual rows. Is there any way by which I can do this for all rows simultaneously with single formula dependoing on number of rows?

Answer (score 0):

I use a macro to do that, the macro works with selected text, you can easily change it to suit your solution:

```
    sub Append_Text()
    'Add right text to the left text
        for each c in Selection
            if c.Value <> "" then c.Offset(0,2).Value = c.Value & c.Offset(0,1).Value
        next
    end sub
```

You select the left side values and run the macro, it would be a good idea to assign a shortcut for the macro to speed up the process.
Let me know if this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this using a single formula such as `=A1&B1`,
then first convert your data as table (select a cell in your data, use the Ribbon menu  **Insert** -> **Table** ) and then use the formula which will fill down automatically.